# Iterating through all subsets of a 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

Assuming I have created an array by using the code below:

```py
import numpy as np 
array = np.random.randint(0, 255, (3,4,4))
```

```
>>> array
array([[[ 72,  11, 158, 252],
        [160,  50, 131, 174],
        [245, 127,  99,   6],
        [152,  25,  58,  96]],

       [[ 29,  37, 211, 215],
        [195,  72, 186,  33],
        [ 12,  68,  44, 241],
        [ 95, 184, 188, 176]],

       [[238,  90, 177,  15],
        [ 48, 221,  41, 236],
        [ 86,  14, 130, 192],
        [ 64,  17,  44, 251]]])
```

Which created a 3d array of 8x8 matrices I would like to go through **all** possible adjacent 2x2 sub-matrices. For example, I would like to get the following matrices from the first matrix:

```
[[72,11],
 [160, 50]]
[[11,158],
 [50, 131]]
[[160,50],
 [245,127]]
etc...
```

Is there a built-in numpy\pytorch method I can use or do I have to implement this iteration?

Comment: `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(array.reshape(-1, array.shape[-1]), (2, 2)).reshape(-1, 2, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) to simply generate the entire matrix:

```
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(array, (1, 2, 2)).reshape(-1, 2, 2)
array([[[ 72,  11],
        [160,  50]],

       [[ 11, 158],
        [ 50, 131]],

       [[158, 252],
        [131, 174]],

       ...

       [[ 14, 130],
        [ 17,  44]],

       [[130, 192],
        [ 44, 251]]])
```

Note that the data will be copied in the last step of reshaping, and the memory consumption of the results generated by large arrays may be unacceptable. <strike>If you just want to iterate over each sub array, you can reshape the original array to generate a view that is easier to iterate:</strike>

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> view = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
...     array.reshape(-1, array.shape[-1]), (2, 2)
... )
>>> for ar in chain.from_iterable(view):
...     print(ar)
...
[[ 72  11]
 [160  50]]
[[ 11 158]
 [ 50 131]]
[[158 252]
 [131 174]]
...
[[ 14 130]
 [ 17  44]]
[[130 192]
 [ 44 251]]
```

<sub>The above method has defects, which will cause the data between two 2d sub arrays to be treated as sub views (such as `[[152, 25], [29, 37]]`). The possible choice is not to use reshape and iterate through multiple loops.</sub>